# TFS / MSBuild - ContinueOnError failing from inner-process non-zero return

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I've got a utility I run mid-build which does a bunch of file-checks. It uses the exit codes from those checks from a commandline tool it uses to determine the next course of action.

The utility itself is exiting 0, but as the commandline process it spawns is not exiting 0, it causes ContinueOnError to trigger a build failure when set to `false`.

I would like to have some sort of way to handle this gracefully. Is there a direct fix or workaround I can use? I would really like to fail the build if my utility fails, but not the inner-process checks, which I know will always generate non-zero returns, if used correctly.

Comment: Are you building locally or using TFS XAML build?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT using the TFS XAMLs with .targets/.proj files